On 24.04 / KDE: How do I permanently configure my screen arrangement?
I installed 24.04 (after having used 22.04), and have now a problem with my display configuration. Under 22.04, I had the following content in /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Monitor"
Identifier "DP-1"
Option "Primary" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier "DP-2"
Option "LeftOf" "DP-1"
EndSection

This seems not to be read. I also tried to switch the order of the screens in the System Settings. This works, but the next time I start KDE, I see the wrong order again.
I am not sure how to fix this, and why xorg.conf is not respected anymore.
